# Как продолжить выполнение программы используя конструкцию try catch в PHP

Tags: php, исключения

Возможно ли проигнорировать эксепшен и продолжить выполнение цикла?

```
try {
    while(true)
    {
      someCode(); // может возвращать исключение
    } 
} catch (SomeCodeException $e) {
   switch($e->getError())
   {
     case 'Some error':
       // как проигнорировать и продолжить выполнение?
       break;
     default:
        exit($e->getError());
       break;
   }
}
```

Спасибо за любые ответы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вынеси цикл наружу, исключение безусловно завершает цикл, находящийся внутри секции `try`:

```
while(true)
{
  try {
    someCode(); // может возвращать исключение
  } catch (SomeCodeException $e) {
    switch($e->getError())
    {
    case 'Some error':
      // как заигнорировать и продолжить выполнение?
      break;
    default:
      exit($e->getError());
      //break; // после exit, break ни к чему
    }
  }
}
```

---

Не нужно делать слишком широких секций `try/catch`.
Могу предложить вынести обработчик в функцию/метод:

```
function exceptionHandler(SomeCodeException $e) {
  switch($e->getError())
  {
  case 'Some error':
    break;
  default:
    exit($e->getError());
  }
}
```

И потом сделать разные секции отлова:

```
try {
  codeBeforeLoop();
} catch (SomeCodeException $e) {
  exceptionHandler($e);
}
while(true)
{
  try {
    someCode(); // может возвращать исключение
  } catch (SomeCodeException $e) {
    exceptionHandler($e);
  }
}
```

Comment: Перед циклом есть ещё код, который не должен выполняться в цикле.

Comment: Который тоже обязан быть в этом же try/catch?

Comment: Да, всё верно .